# mySQL COALESCE filtering

Tags: mysql, sql, coalesce

Hello fellow Stackoverflowers! I've got a query I'm working on that I need to filter out 0's but it's not removing those records and I can't seem to figure out why.

Please see below,

```
SELECT  disb_sum, pl_balance,
      COALESCE(p.pl_balance - pd.disb_sum, p.pl_balance - 0) AS pledge_balance
FROM      contacts c
LEFT JOIN pledges p ON c.c_no = p.c_no
LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT   pl_no, disb_status, disb_no, disb_amount, SUM(disb_amount) AS disb_sum
        FROM     disbursements
        WHERE disb_status = 1
        GROUP BY pl_no
        ) pd ON p.pl_no = pd.pl_no
GROUP BY p.pl_no
HAVING pledge_balance > "0"
ORDER BY  c.c_last
```

***OUTPUT***

```
# disb_sum, pl_balance, pledge_balance
NULL, '5000.00', '5000.00'
NULL, '5000.00', '5000.00'
'25000.00', '25000.00', '0.00'
NULL, '100000.00', '100000.00'
NULL, '6000.00', '6000.00'
NULL, '2500.00', '2500.00'
NULL, '1500.00', '1500.00'
```

I've tried adding an additional parameter and disb_sum <> disb_sum but get the same result set.

Answer (score 0):

```
GROUP BY p.pl_no    
HAVING pledge_balance > "0"
```

Try this:

```
WHERE pledge_balance > "0"
GROUP BY p.pl_no
```

I can't see why you are grouping by that column since it's not a resultset column anyway.

Comment: Hey @Niloct, good point. I tried your suggestion but I'm still getting the same result set. Thanks for you're support!

Answer (score 0):

If Niloct's answer doesn't work, try:

```
HAVING pledge_balance <> "0"
```

Comment: Thanks @AdrianLynch but I'm still getting the same results.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `pledge_balance` *is* greater than zero.  But, it is something like 0.0001.  This would especially be possible if you were using floating point numbers rather than fixed point numbers.

So, you can try:

```
HAVING pledge_balance > 0.005
```

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff but I'm still getting the same result :( I tried .005 and .0001

Comment: @chasecabrera . . . Hmmm, that would seem to indicate that this theory is not correct.  Why are the numbers in the output surrounded by single quotes?  This is highly suspicious, because the values in the `SELECT` would only be numbers.

Comment: Totally agree, I checked the column type and both read as decimals(12,2) so there isn't a type discrepancy.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out what the problem was with my having parameter so I loaded the query into a temporary table and filtered it that way. Thank you guys for your prompt feedback and assistance!